# Issues with reverse shell

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, reverse-shell

good morning everyone i am having a issue with reverse shell from this website (https://github.com/AyyoubOuakkaha/Younioner). When i run server and client the code works but the problem is when i run setup.py im getting a this error below

*UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'console'warnings.warn(msg) usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]or:setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]or: setup.py --help-commandsor:setup.py cmd --helperror: no commands supplied`. is there a way to fix this issue and put the script on a usb drive and run it on other pc.*

If there a way to fix this issue can you executable on a usb drive and run the script on other pc?

Comment: Have you tried running `setup.py --help`, as the error message suggests?

Comment: no how do i go about this?

Comment: Just like how you're running `setup.py`, I guess? But instead of running just `setup.py`, run `setup.py --help`. If you want to install something, you normally run `setup.py install`

Comment: do i run it on the cmd or on pycharm or idle? sorry i am new to reverse shell and python.

Comment: It should be simpler to run this via the command line

Comment: ok i did and now it says Unknown distribution option: 'console'warnings.warn(msg) running install,running build,running install_egg_info. do you know what this mean?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Does anything say `error` in the output?

Comment: no just a warning and creating build and copying unknown.egg -info

Comment: Then everything should've installed fine

Comment: . so what do i do next and will this work on usb?

Comment: I have no idea. You should read [the `README`](https://github.com/AyyoubOuakkaha/Younioner/blob/master/README.md) for instructions

Comment: one more thing what does Unknown distribution option: 'console' mean. that probably the issue